# What programming/template language is this?

Tags: php, django, codeigniter, django-templates

I have gotten a project(website) to work on that was already in progress.

It is coded in CodeIgniter but is using some weird syntax i havent seen before. Google-ing lead me to the answer that it is Django:

```
    {% if logged_in %}    // THIS IS DJANGO?
<nav id="main-nav">
    <ul id="nav">
    <li>......
    {% else %}
```

Ok i get the upper part, but this confuses me:

```
{*
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app/models/map.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app/views/dialog.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app/models/goal.js"></script>
.....
 *}
```

What does {*  mean?

Also when i run this site in wamp or my server the code that is between {* is not generated.

Any explanation is appreciated, i am over due with this project and desperate with no time to google to much.

Comment: {**} is not a valid Django template tag. {##} would be a comment...it's entirely possible someone was attempting to comment out those script references.

Comment: Could be...once i remove them the code generates, hm i find it weird its used in multiple places.

Comment: Could also be [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/). Which has almost identical syntax to Django.

Comment: @dan-klasson could be right. Check out https://github.com/dilantha/codeigniter-twig

Comment: hm it does look like its especially because there are tags within html exactly like this one:  {{ base_url() }} ,  . But i have searched all files with powershell and there is no mention of Twig library's anywhere in the code?

Comment: I will also add that some of the pages start with:  {% extends "base.html" %}  which i so in some posts is related to Django templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its H2O https://github.com/speedmax/h2o-php/wiki

"H2O is markup language for PHP that has taken a lot of inspiration from Django." hence the similarity..